# How to tell when IndexedDB was manually closed?

Tags: javascript, events, indexeddb, thread-synchronization

I need to create an object store when upgrade phase of the database passed. To achieve that, I am trying to close and reopen the database with a new version and create the store in `onupgradeneeded` event.

IndexedDB has a [close()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBDatabase/close) method that

> Returns immediately and closes the connection to a database in a separate thread.

However, it does not return IDBRequest like other similar methods. This method waits for running transactions to finish, so the closing can be delayed. I need to know about the close event, so I can reopen it. There is an [onclose](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBDatabase/close_event) event, that does not fire, because the connection is not closed unexpectedly:

> Fired when the database connection is **unexpectedly** closed. Also available via the onclose property.

I don't want to be rude to periodically check the [onblocked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBOpenDBRequest/blocked_event) event in opening attempts. In my tests `IndexedDB.open()` reopens the database succesfully, but I can't push it to production if it is not guaranteed. In the [w3 specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#dom-idbfactory-open) they write about *done flag*, but I can't find it in the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can? If I understood you correctly, maybe Joshua Bell's response to [How do I check if an indexedDB instance is open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46996600/how-do-i-check-if-an-indexeddb-instance-is-open) helps answer your question.